# Next js: If getServerSideProps runs on the server can i call node.js functions to access server resources?

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to read and return a list of files from the server and pass to my component using getServerSideProps on a next js page (in /pages)

If getServerSideProps runs on the server can i then (somehow) call node.js functions to access server resources? This would be great for making a dynamic menu system that reflects the file structure on the server.

My first attempt has failed because Next js doesnt recognise node.js common js imports. Is there a correct way to access the full set of node.js resource and functions from within a component?

/pages/home.tsx

```
// requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// these also failed - next js cant find them
// import * as path from 'path'
// import * as fs from 'fs';


function readFiles() {
    // joining path of directory 
    const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
    // passing directoryPath and callback function
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
        //handling error
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        } 
        //listing all files using forEach
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the file
            console.log(file); 
        });
    });
    return files;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
      props: {
          readFiles();
      }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
```

error on server:

```
|next-next12  | https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
0|next-next12  | wait  - compiling...
0|next-next12  | error - ./pages/home.tsx:4:11
0|next-next12  | Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
0|next-next12  |   2 | //requiring path and fs modules
0|next-next12  |   3 | const path = require('path');
0|next-next12  | > 4 | const fs = require('fs');
```

Is this possible? If not are we limited only to fetching data in getServerSideProps. It would be great to access the server too.

Comment: Where is this code located? you can only call `getServerSideProps` in your "pages"

Comment: sorry yes its in the correct place attached to a page. I have been experimenting and I have no such problems placing the code in /api and then fetching from getServerSideProps which is an unncessary step. It would be better to insert node.js code directly into getServerSideProps and omit the fetch.

Comment: Not only is it possible, it's also recommended to do so. Are you using `fs` or `readFiles` anywhere else in that file? Could you provide a [mre]? I can't reproduce the error with the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `getServerSideProps` you can write node.js code as if you were writing it on the server.

You can also import server packages in ES Modules convention:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
```

BUT you can only use them inside `getServerSideProps`

So your code should look like this:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  function readFiles() {
    // joining path of directory 
    const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
    // passing directoryPath and callback function
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      //handling error
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
      } 
      //listing all files using forEach
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
        console.log(file); 
      });
    });
    return files;
  }
  return {
    props: {
      readFiles();
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```